# How to create a Query where only the latest addition to a textfile displays in the listbox?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to create a query Where only the latest Booking added to the text file is displayed in the list box.

I've tried to somehow select the first index but can't get my head around it as I'm very new to coding

```
Dim strBooking() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("food.txt")
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLatestBooking.Click

    Dim BookingsQuery = From Booking In strBooking
                        Where Booking = (0)
                        Select Booking

    For Each Booking As String In BookingsQuery
        lstLatestBooking.Items.Add(Booking)
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error when I run my code 
At this part of the code:

```
Where Booking = (0)
```

the error code that comes up

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: Was the "latest addition to the textfile" added to the beginning of the file or the end of the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the first line in the array you have generated by reading the textfile, there is no need to use linq at all. You can just reference the first entry in the array with strBooking(0):

```
Dim strBooking() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("food.txt")
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLatestBooking.Click

    If strBooking.Length > 0 Then
        lstLatestBooking.Items.Add(strBooking(0))
    End If       
End Sub
```

You should [read about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/).

If you want to do this with linq, just use [.first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
If strBooking.Length > 0 Then
    lstLatestBooking.Items.Add(strBooking.First())
End If
```